# alembic how to merge all revision files to one file?

Tags: python, flask, alembic

There are more than 100 files in  alembic version directory. How to use alembic command to merge these file into a one file?

I am try to use this:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

but doesn't work! Anyone has good idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have all the models in models.py (or whatever you use for models), it should be possible to achieve your goal by recreating migrations in a single file. Like this:

1. Point Alembic to a different and empty database
2. run `alembic revision --autogenerate`
3. You'll get the mirroring revision in a single file.

Comment: I clear the database, then run the command, but there is an error: `FAILED: Target database is not up to date.`

Comment: Try moving all the migrations away from versions folder and resetting the eversion_num in alembic_version table.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Miguel will kill me, but I always start alembic with an empty model and alembic script. When I want to consolidate I roll back to this one, remove the other migration scripts and create a new migration script that only contains what is currently in the model.

Miguel suggests merging the files by hand. This is a great option, but depending on the dev it could be very error prone as well as difficult to cancel some things out as needed.